# Can you use ImportXML to scrape a specific regional version of a page?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using IMPORTXML to scrape the price for about twenty games from https://gg.deals/ The problem however is that it's scraping the default version which lists prices and deals for the US region. These are often different so a straight up currency conversion won't work e.g. https://gg.deals/dlc/world-of-warcraft-shadowlands/ lists €35.60 as the best EU Keyshop price but $28.76 for the best US one. I'd like it to scrape the EU prices and I'm wondering is there any way to add this data into the IMPORTXML call?

Comment: @player0 proxy link! region defaults to ip address

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use a proxy to spoof the region you want to grab prices for.

https://uk.4everproxy.com worked for me to grab EU prices.